# Return to previous state on error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular `ui-router` in my application and whenever an error occurs, e.g. `HTTP 404`, `HTTP 500` etc, I would like an error page to be displayed with details of the error and a single button to enable the user to return to previous state or page they were on.

I am using a HTTP response interceptor to watch for HTTP errors and then do a `$state.go('error')` to bring up the error page.

I am also doing a `$state.go('error')` in all error promise functions as well.

I have the following code in my controller to create a restore point that will reload the controller when the user clicks on the 'go back' link on the error page.

```
// create a restore point for the error page to return to.
$rootScope.previousState = $state.current.name;
$rootScope.previousStateParams = $state.current.params;
```

This is my error.html page:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <div class="medium">{{errorMessage}}</div>
    <br />
    <div>{{reason}}</div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <a href="#" data-ng-click="return()">Go back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my `error state` config:

```
$stateProvider.state('error', {
    templateUrl: paths.templates + 'error.html',
    params: ['errorMessage', 'reason'],
    controller: function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $scope.errorMessage = $stateParams.errorMessage;
        $scope.reason = $stateParams.reason;
        $scope.return = function ()
        {
            console.log($rootScope.previousStateParams);
            $state.transitionTo($rootScope.previousState, $rootScope.previousStateParams, {
                reload: true,
                inherit: false,
                notify: true
            });
        };
    },
    data: {
        access: [roles.all]
    }
```

What I am looking for is the cleanest method of storing the current state of each controller so that clicking the 'go back' button will reload the controller with whatever parameters that were originally passed in.

I have tried using the following code in my module `run` bootstrap method, but when I click on a link to display an order it traverses to a state called `order-edit` and then attempts to fetch the order from the database via REST.

If the order URI cannot found I get a HTTP 404 error correctly displayed in the error page, and when I click on the 'go back' button it is re-firing the previous REST action ad-infinitum, which isn't what I want.

What I'd like to happen is for the 'go back' button to take me back two steps to the page that displays my orders in a table.  To do this I would probably have to store the current state manually so that going back will reload the correct state, but I'm concerned this could get messy with lots of controllers making it difficult to implement.

```
$rootScope.previousState;
$rootScope.previousStateParams;
$rootScope.currentState;

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
    $rootScope.previousState = from.name;
    $rootScope.previousStateParams = fromParams;
    $rootScope.currentState = to.name;
    console.log('Previous state:' + $rootScope.previousState);
    console.log('Current state:' + $rootScope.currentState);
});
```

I would like to avoid manually setting the current state in all of my controllers as the application could easily end up in the wrong controller if the state specified in the 'go back' button is not set to the correct state.

I hope this all makes sense?

Comment: Is it important that the error page be a page?  I would choose to  use an alert toast or modal before I would go the route route.

Comment: I guess it doesn't have to be a page as I thought this was the normal way of alerting errors in one place. I am happy to consider an alternative way of alerting users to errors.  Is [this](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) what you mean about alert toast?

Comment: There are many ways of doing that type of alert, I think the fact that you have data binding at your disposal allows for many seamless UI techniques - popups, toasters, modals, dialogs.  These all seem much easier than jumping over to another page just to then go back.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments, I will look at implementing toasters as this seems to fit my requirements better.